# Does an XML sitemap need to have a .xml extension?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap

Im using a CMS that generates a sitemap automatically but without ".xml".IS this ok?

Can we put this is our robots.txt:

```
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap
```

or must it be:

```
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Cool URIs do not use extensions at all: https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI see "What to leave out"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not mandatory. Google's guidelines allow xml, txt and html formats. Look into [guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668) to get further info.

Note: if sitemap has any other format as xml, it must be encoded as utf-8 and contain nothing more then urls one per line. Sitemap in xml format allows containing of some additional informations.

Comment: The generated format is XML  but has no ".xml"  file extension.  Really wanted to know how important it was to have the ".xml" extension.

Comment: if the file is correct formatted, Google will recognize it not dependently on the file extention. You can test it through implementing it into the search console.

Answer (score 2):

After seven years of using a sitemap with an ASPX extension, we have had our sitemaps stuck in a "Couldn't fetch" status for weeks.  When we added a rewrite rule that forced sitemap.xml to the aspx page, our sitemap was fetched and processed within a day.  It may not be required, but it appears to have some priority.

Answer (score -1):

You can have 2 types of sitemap. One for Website users which can be in html or text and another for only Search Engine which is needed only in .xml format.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question they are asking. They want to know if their XML sitemap needs to have a file extension or not.